# When will G1 GC allocate objects in old generation directly

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, g1gc

In my gc log, there are many objects are allocated to old generations (ALLOC(Old) logs), current threshold is 15, my objects age is only 1, i.e, these objects will not be promoted to old generations, i guess is there any condition when objects will be allocated to old generations directly in G1 GC? Thanks in advance!

**Excerpt of GC log:**

```
grep "ALLOC(Old)" gc.log | wc -l

387

grep "thres" gc.log

Desired survivor size 1207959552 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)

Desired survivor size 1207959552 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)

- age   1:   37707272 bytes,   37707272 total
```

**JDK version:**

- openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-b10)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)

*********Update on 2020/01/31****************

It is not humongous objects,gc log will show humongous object allocation in another way, pls kindly refer to following gc log excerpt, thx!

```
>> grep "StartsH" gc.log | wc -l

51

>> grep "ContinuesH" gc.log | wc -l

324

>> grep "ALLOC(Old)" gc.log | wc -l

528
```

Reference: https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/collecting-and-reading-g1-garbage-collector-logs-part-2

Answer (score 2):

This happens when a big Object (50% or more from a single region) is allocated. Even the [source code has a comment saying that](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/heapRegion.hpp#l295).

Just remember that arrays are Objects too, so when you are allocating a big array of primitives, you might fall into this category. That being said, you have a very recent JVM version, where these very big objects can be reclaimed as part of a young collection.

**EDIT**

`ALLOC(OLD)` does not mean that your application has started allocating objects in the old generation. It just means that this particular region, started being *used* during this GC cycle. [here is the method declaration](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/g1HRPrinter.hpp#l51) and [here is a usage of it](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/g1CollectedHeap.cpp#l4642), in a method called `G1CollectedHeap::new_gc_alloc_region` - a very appropriate name IMO.

Comment: Thanks for ur comments! Actually it is not humongous objects, gc log will show humongous object allocation in another way, pls kindly refer to following gc log excerpt, thx!

# grep "StartsH" gc.log | wc -l

51

# grep "ContinuesH" gc.log | wc -l

324

# grep "ALLOC(Old)" gc.log | wc -l

528

Reference: https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/collecting-and-reading-g1-garbage-collector-logs-part-2